# Finding UUIDs in Android 2.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am writing a program which needs to be run in Android 2.0. I am currently trying to connect my android device to an embedded bluetooth chip. I have been given information as to use fetchuidsWithSDP(), or getUuids(), but the page I read explained that these methods are hidden in the 2.0 SDK, and must be called using reflection. I have no idea what that means and there is no explanation. There is example code given, but very little explanation behind it. I was hoping someone could help me understand what is actually going on here, as I am very new to Android development.

```
String action = "android.bleutooth.device.action.UUID";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( action );
registerReceiver( mReceiver, filter );
```

The page I read also says that in the first line bluetooth is spelled "bleutooth" on purpose. If anyone can explain that, I would appreciate that as well as it makes no sense to me, unless the developers made a typo.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    BluetoothDevice deviceExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.Device");
    Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
}
```

};

I am having trouble grasping how exactly I find the correct UUID for my embedded bluetooth chip. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am going to add the rest of my onCreate() method so you can see what I'm working with.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up window View
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Initialize the button to scan for other devices.
    btnScanDevice = (Button) findViewById( R.id.scandevice );

    // Initialize the TextView which displays the current state of the bluetooth
    stateBluetooth = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.bluetoothstate );
    startBluetooth();

    // Initialize the ListView of the nearby bluetooth devices which are found.
    listDevicesFound = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.devicesfound );
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( AndroidBluetooth.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    listDevicesFound.setAdapter( btArrayAdapter );

    CheckBlueToothState();

    // Add an OnClickListener to the scan button.
    btnScanDevice.setOnClickListener( btnScanDeviceOnClickListener );

    // Register an ActionFound Receiver to the bluetooth device for ACTION_FOUND
    registerReceiver( ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND ) );

    // Add an item click listener to the ListView
    listDevicesFound.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
      {
          // Save the device the user chose.
          myBtDevice = btDevicesFound.get( arg2 );

          // Open a socket to connect to the device chosen.
          try {
              btSocket = myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID );
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions" );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer One" );
          }

          // Cancel the discovery process to save battery.
          myBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

          // Update the current state of the Bluetooth.
          CheckBlueToothState();

          // Attempt to connect the socket to the bluetooth device.
          try {
              btSocket.connect();                 
              // Open I/O streams so the device can send/receive data.
              iStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
              oStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "IO Exception" );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer Two" );
          }
      } 
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you probably give the link to that page?

Comment: Yeah, it's right here

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/11/android-bluetooth-rfcomm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably better off using the synchronous version so you don't have to deal with all the moving parts of setting up the `BroadcastReceiver`.  Since you are always doing this on the heels of discovery, the cached data will always be fresh.

Here the functionality of getting the UUID data encapsulated up into a method.  This code was in one of the comments of the blog post you linked:

```
//In SDK15 (4.0.3) this method is now public as
//Bluetooth.fetchUuisWithSdp() and BluetoothDevice.getUuids()
public ParcelUuid[] servicesFromDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class[] par = {};
        Method method = cl.getMethod("getUuids", par);
        Object[] args = {};
        ParcelUuid[] retval = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(device, args);
        return retval;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then call this method anywhere in your code, passing it a `BluetoothDevice` and getting back an array of UUIDs for that device's services (typically for small embedded stacks the array is only 1 item); something like:

```
  // Save the device the user chose.
  myBtDevice = btDevicesFound.get( arg2 );
  //Query the device's services
  ParcelUuid[] uuids = servicesFromDevice(myBtDevice);

  // Open a socket to connect to the device chosen.
  try {
      btSocket = myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
  } catch ( IOException e ) {
      Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions" );
  } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
      Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer One" );
  }
```

in the block you posted above.

As a side note, calling all this code in the manner you have will make your application sad later.  The block of code calling `connect()` and obtaining the streams should be done on a background thread because that method will block for a period of time and calling this code on the main thread will freeze your UI temporarily.  You should move that code into an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` like the BluetoothChat sample in the SDK does.

HTH

Comment: If you happen to take a look at this, I came back to this code again today and realized its still not working for me. I have posted a new question if you have a chance to help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105891/how-do-i-find-the-proper-uuid

Comment: @Devunwired  hi I am getting ParcelUuid[] retval as null when preferring above code. Can you help in this??

Comment: @nick This method only works if you have recently done a discovery operation, as it pulls data from the cache.  If you need fresh data from a device you will need to look at `fetchUuidsWithSdp()` instead.  Both of these methods are now public in Android 4.0.3 also, so you may try testing on a device with a newer version to make sure the issue isn't elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @Devunwired I have gone through your site.Actually the client requirement on only Android 2.2 . Thats why I am working on this.I just want the UUid of my device and afterdiscovery, the uuid of the other device whom i do connect with my device. I have browse on net. Did googling, but unable to find any solution to this.

Comment: @Devunwired Im using uuids[0].getUuid() this for UUid from your method servicesFromDevice(device). it will pair automatically? or we need to code for pairing?

Comment: This works but how can reflection override API levels? the getUUIDs method should only be available on API >=15 but this also works on 13

Comment: The methods were only ***public*** starting in 4.0.3., but they've been a part of the core source code since ~2.0

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue and this is how I solved it for Android 2.3.3. I think the same solution will work for android 2.2 also.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device: "+device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            devices.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            list.add(device);

        }
        else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am Here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done Scanning..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Iterator<BluetoothDevice> itr = list.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    BluetoothDevice dev=itr.next();
                    if(dev.fetchUuidsWithSdp())
                    {
                        Parcelable a[]=dev.getUuids();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dev.getName()+":"+a[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
};
```